# pythonでprint()が含まれるものが全てエラーになってしまう

Tags: python

どんなに簡単なものでも print() が入ると全てエラーになってしまいます。
初心者向けのサイトからコピペしても同様です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問をするときはコードを画像で貼り付けるのではなく、実際にコードを書き込むと見やすくなり回答がつきやすくなると思います！/[参考](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Python3 においては、`print` は変数です。`print` を呼び出し、

> ```
> 'tuple' object is not callable
> ```

というエラーメッセージが出たということは、`print` という変数の中身が[タプル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)になっているという事です。

おそらく、提示されたコードより上の箇所でそのような代入が行なわれているのでしょう。例えば以下のようなコードが考えられます。

```py
print = (text1, text2)
```

あるいは、

```py
print = text1,
```

としても、末尾のコンマにより、タプルとなります。

---

#### Notebook の編集結果を正確に反映させるためには

Jupyter Notebook 系の実行環境をご利用のようですので、念のため確認しておきますが、一度実行したコードを消去したとしても、動いているカーネル（ランタイム）への影響（変数の内容など）が消えることはありません。カーネル（ランタイム）の再起動、及び全てのセルの実行を行なう必要があります。